# Change source files in bulk

Tags: excel, vba

I have a master file that links to a lot different files that are named per month.
The source is set up in this kind of way:
C:\Overview\2023\Data\Filename23.xlsx

Where I would like to change \2023\ to \2024\ and 23.xlsx to 24.xlsx

I do not want to work with find and replace where I look for 23 and change it to 24, because it might change values that I do not want to be changed.

As I have a lot of files where I link to, changing it manually through "Data" & "Edit links" would be a real pain due to the workload.

Does anyone know an easier way to change multiple parts of the link in one go? If I try to firstly change the folder name \2023\ to \2024\ it asks me to select the source file manually (because the 23.xlsx extension doesn't exist in the 2024 folder).

As each file has its own unique name, I cannot just use the find and replace function from C:\Overview\2023\Data\Filename23.xlsx to C:\Overview\2024\Data\Filename24.xlsx as I would need to do it for each specific file.

Does anyone have an easy solution for this?

Comment: You could loop through all cells with affected formulas and use Replace(Replace(cell.Value, "\2023\", "\2024\"), "23.xlsx","24.xlsx")

Comment: "Edit links" can be [automated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.changelink).

Comment: How can I loop through all cells in a specific sheet to make these changes in vba? As it's a quite large file sadly

Comment: You shouldn't be looping through cells at all. Use `Workbook.ChangeLink`.

Comment: Thanks, I used Workbook.ChangeLink and it worked like a charm!